# ifconfig new ip address overwriting main ip

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, ip, ifconfig

Today I tried adding a new, additional ip-address my hosting-service gave me. But I encountered a problem. I entered this command into the cmd: `ifconfig enp35s0:1 167.235.117.188 netmask 255.255.255.0 hw ether 00:50:56:00:F9:3B up`. But somehow it is overwriting the main-ip. Can anybody help me out on this one? Thanks!

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu 22.04 as your tag suggests, then use the `ip` command, rather than the legacy `ifconfig`. `ip address add dev ...` should do just what you want.

Comment: Also, if you want the IP address to persist after a reboot, you will need to add it to your netplan configuration (in `/etc/netplan`).

Comment: Alright. Thank u so much! @zwets

Comment: @zwets I added my configuration to netplan but it's still the same. The primary-ip is beeing overwritten.

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp35s0:
      addresses:
        - 167.235.117.189/32
        - 167.235.117.188/24
        - 2a01:4f8:2200:21cd::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 167.235.117.129
        - to: default
          via: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 185.12.64.2
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1
          - 185.12.64.1
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2

Comment: Please add this information to your question, so that it is legible and has value for future visitors. The comments are for volatile information only.

Comment: Have you removed the legacy `/etc/network/interfaces` (and best also the `net-tools` package)?